# Is there a standard way to get deviations/error bars on a rSNNS model

Tags: r, neural-network

Is there a standard way to get error bars/deviations from neural network predictions? I understand this is a problem with fitted models but an approach from intuition would suggest smaller error bars near the core of the sample and larger error bars further away from the sample as in an AR model prediction. What's the standard approach to this problem?

Let me know if this should be moved to stats.

Comment: error bars? are you making graphs?

Comment: No. Just interested in the general concept of extracting a deviation/distribution for a neural network prediction.